# Error CS0052 Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'FormDataEntryFilterType' is less accessible than field 'FormDataEntry.type'

Tags: c#, enums, public

I do not know what to do with this problem
He does not accept " public " in enum FormDataEntryFilterType and I want it to change it from the outside
If anyone can help me, thanks a lot

the code :

```
    enum FormDataEntryFilterType
{
    integerNumber,
    DecimalNumber,
    String
}

public partial class FormDataEntry : Form
{

    public static string InputResult;
    **public** FormDataEntryFilterType type = FormDataEntryFilterType.DecimalNumber;


    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FormDataEntry.type` field is public, but its enum type is private. Your enum defaults to **private** because no access modifier has been specified.

To fix this, you can make your enum public:

```
public enum FormDataEntryFilterType
{
    integerNumber,
    DecimalNumber,
    String
}
```

Comment: I forgot that :/ 
thanks a lot - it's working

Answer (score 1):

`FormDataEntryFilterType` is private to the assembly.  You cannot then return its value from a `public` method, because the caller does not have access to the `enum`.

Change the `enum` to `public`

```
public enum FormDataEntryFilterType
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: it's working .. Thanks very much